# drupal Bootstrap main menu toggle button no work when add second menu to block region

Tags: theming

[image]

[image]

the right side is the main menu toggle using superfish menu, and the blue color area is the second menu to the block region in bootstrap help region block. The toggle menu can not drop down. If i take out the second menu the main menu toggle button is work. Please help for figure out what is the problem.